# SQL RANK() versus ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm confused about the differences between these.  Running the following SQL gets me two idential result sets.  Can someone please explain the differences?

```
SELECT ID, [Description], RANK()       OVER(PARTITION BY StyleID ORDER BY ID) as 'Rank'      FROM SubStyle
SELECT ID, [Description], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StyleID ORDER BY ID) as 'RowNumber' FROM SubStyle
```

Answer (score 294, accepted):

**ROW_NUMBER :** Returns a unique number for each row starting with 1. For rows that have duplicate values,numbers are arbitarily assigned.

**Rank :** Assigns a unique number for each row starting with 1,except for rows that have duplicate values,in which case the same ranking is assigned and a gap appears in the sequence for each duplicate ranking.

Answer (score 557):

You will only see the difference if you have ties within a partition for a particular ordering value.

`RANK` and  `DENSE_RANK` are deterministic in this case, all rows with the same value for both the ordering and partitioning columns will end up with an equal result, whereas `ROW_NUMBER` will arbitrarily (non deterministically) assign an incrementing result to the tied rows.

**Example:** (All rows have the same `StyleID` so are in the same partition and within that partition the first 3 rows are tied when ordered by `ID`)

```
WITH T(StyleID, ID)
     AS (SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1,2)
SELECT *,
       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY StyleID ORDER BY ID)       AS [RANK],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StyleID ORDER BY ID) AS [ROW_NUMBER],
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY StyleID ORDER BY ID) AS [DENSE_RANK]
FROM   T
```

Returns

```
StyleID     ID       RANK      ROW_NUMBER      DENSE_RANK
----------- -------- --------- --------------- ----------
1           1        1         1               1
1           1        1         2               1
1           1        1         3               1
1           2        4         4               2
```

You can see that for the three identical rows the `ROW_NUMBER` increments, the `RANK` value remains the same then it leaps to `4`. `DENSE_RANK` also assigns the same rank to all three rows but then the next distinct value is assigned a value of 2.

Comment: Thanks for a great example. Helped me realize I've wrongly been using RANK() function when ROW_NUMBER() would have been much more appropriate.

Comment: Perfect! Have been using `ROW_NUMBER` where I should have used `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: For fast searchers: pay attention to PARTITIONed column in this example. It has only one unique element! If you want "row number" column for the hole table you should use MAP functions (ROW_NUMBER for example) without partition. Because in case of adding partition on column with more than 1 unique element the internal scheduler (planner) will apply MAP functions independently inside each partition (the task will become REDUCE operation and your table will be splitted by keys).

Answer (score 50):

[This article covers an interesting relationship between `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()`](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/sql-trick-row_number-is-to-select-what-dense_rank-is-to-select-distinct/) (the `RANK()` function is not treated specifically). When you need a generated `ROW_NUMBER()` on a `SELECT DISTINCT` statement, the `ROW_NUMBER()` will produce distinct values *before* they are removed by the `DISTINCT` keyword. E.g. this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  v, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v) row_number
FROM t
ORDER BY v, row_number
```

... might produce this result (`DISTINCT` has no effect):

```
+---+------------+
| V | ROW_NUMBER |
+---+------------+
| a |          1 |
| a |          2 |
| a |          3 |
| b |          4 |
| c |          5 |
| c |          6 |
| d |          7 |
| e |          8 |
+---+------------+
```

Whereas this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  v, 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY v) row_number
FROM t
ORDER BY v, row_number
```

... produces what you probably want in this case:

```
+---+------------+
| V | ROW_NUMBER |
+---+------------+
| a |          1 |
| b |          2 |
| c |          3 |
| d |          4 |
| e |          5 |
+---+------------+
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` clause of the `DENSE_RANK()` function will need all other columns from the `SELECT DISTINCT` clause to work properly.

The reason for this is that logically, [window functions are calculated before `DISTINCT` is applied](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/).

#### All three functions in comparison

Using PostgreSQL / Sybase / SQL standard syntax (`WINDOW` clause):

```
SELECT
  v,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (window) row_number,
  RANK()       OVER (window) rank,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (window) dense_rank
FROM t
WINDOW window AS (ORDER BY v)
ORDER BY v
```

... you'll get:

```
+---+------------+------+------------+
| V | ROW_NUMBER | RANK | DENSE_RANK |
+---+------------+------+------------+
| a |          1 |    1 |          1 |
| a |          2 |    1 |          1 |
| a |          3 |    1 |          1 |
| b |          4 |    4 |          2 |
| c |          5 |    5 |          3 |
| c |          6 |    5 |          3 |
| d |          7 |    7 |          4 |
| e |          8 |    8 |          5 |
+---+------------+------+------------+
```

Comment: Both ROW_NUMBER and DENSE_RANK produce values before distinct is applied. Actually all ranking function or any function produces results before DISTINCT is applied.

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis: Absolutely. I've updated my answer with a link to a blog post, where I've explained the [true order of SQL operations](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/)

Comment: `DISTINCT` aside, I don't understand how does the query know to apply `DENSE_RANK()` based on values in the `V` column without `PARTITION BY`? Does it use the column you ordered by?

Comment: @Lukas: Ranking functions assing a rank according to ordering, yes. I recommend reading a good tutorial, e.g. this one here: https://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/08/understanding-window-functions/

Answer (score 26):

*Simple query without partition clause:*

```
select 
    sal, 
    RANK() over(order by sal desc) as Rank,
    DENSE_RANK() over(order by sal desc) as DenseRank,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(order by sal desc) as RowNumber
from employee
```

*Output:*

```
    --------|-------|-----------|----------
    sal     |Rank   |DenseRank  |RowNumber
    --------|-------|-----------|----------
    5000    |1      |1          |1
    3000    |2      |2          |2
    3000    |2      |2          |3
    2975    |4      |3          |4
    2850    |5      |4          |5
    --------|-------|-----------|----------
```

Comment: Simplest example so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Quite a bit:

The rank of a row is one plus the number of ranks that come before the row in question.

Row_number is the distinct rank of rows, without any gap in the ranking.

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/marcoadf/bidn-blog/379/ranking-functions-row_number-vs-rank-vs-dense_rank-vs-ntile

Comment: Ah, I think this is what I was missing -> Row_number is the distinct rank of rows, without any gap in the ranking.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't done anything with rank, but I discovered this today with row_number().

```
select item, name, sold, row_number() over(partition by item order by sold) as row from table_name
```

This will result in some repeating row numbers since in my case each name holds all items. Each item will be ordered by how many were sold.

```
+--------+------+-----+----+
|glasses |store1|  30 | 1  |
|glasses |store2|  35 | 2  |
|glasses |store3|  40 | 3  |
|shoes   |store2|  10 | 1  |
|shoes   |store1|  20 | 2  |
|shoes   |store3|  22 | 3  |
+--------+------+-----+----+
```

Answer (score -1):

Note, all these windowing functions return an integer-like value.

Often the database will choose a BIGINT datatype, and this take much more space than we need.  And, we will rarely need a range from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Cast the results as a BYTEINT, SMALLINT, or INTEGER.

These modern systems and hardware are so strong, so you may never see a meaningflul extra use of resources, but I think it's best-practice.

Answer (score -2):

Look this example.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].#TestTable(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [create_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [info1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [info2] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
)
```

Insert some data

```
INSERT INTO dbo.#TestTable (id, create_date, info1, info2)
VALUES (1, '1/1/09', 'Blue', 'Green')
INSERT INTO dbo.#TestTable (id, create_date, info1, info2)
VALUES (1, '1/2/09', 'Red', 'Yellow')
INSERT INTO dbo.#TestTable (id, create_date, info1, info2)
VALUES (1, '1/3/09', 'Orange', 'Purple')
INSERT INTO dbo.#TestTable (id, create_date, info1, info2)
VALUES (2, '1/1/09', 'Yellow', 'Blue')
INSERT INTO dbo.#TestTable (id, create_date, info1, info2)
VALUES (2, '1/5/09', 'Blue', 'Orange')
INSERT INTO dbo.#TestTable (id, create_date, info1, info2)
VALUES (3, '1/2/09', 'Green', 'Purple')
INSERT INTO dbo.#TestTable (id, create_date, info1, info2)
VALUES (3, '1/8/09', 'Red', 'Blue')
```

Repeat same Values for 1

> INSERT INTO dbo.#TestTable (id, create_date, info1, info2) VALUES (1,
>   '1/1/09', 'Blue', 'Green')

Look All

```
SELECT * FROM #TestTable
```

Look your results

```
SELECT Id,
    create_date,
    info1,
    info2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY create_date DESC) AS RowId,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY create_date DESC)    AS [RANK]
FROM #TestTable
```

Need to understand the different

Answer (score -2):

Also, pay attention to ORDER BY in PARTITION (Standard AdventureWorks db is used for example) when using RANK.

> SELECT    as1.SalesOrderID,   as1.SalesOrderDetailID,     RANK() OVER
>   (PARTITION BY as1.SalesOrderID ORDER BY as1.SalesOrderID ) ranknoequal
>   ,     RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY as1.SalesOrderID ORDER BY
>   as1.SalesOrderDetailId ) ranknodiff  FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail as1
>   WHERE SalesOrderId = 43659 ORDER BY SalesOrderDetailId;

Gives result:

SalesOrderID    SalesOrderDetailID  rank_same_as_partition  rank_salesorderdetailid
43659   1   1   1
43659   2   1   2
43659   3   1   3
43659   4   1   4
43659   5   1   5
43659   6   1   6
43659   7   1   7
43659   8   1   8
43659   9   1   9
43659   10  1   10
43659   11  1   11
43659   12  1   12

But if change order by to (use OrderQty :

> SELECT    as1.SalesOrderID,   as1.OrderQty,   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY
>   as1.SalesOrderID ORDER BY as1.SalesOrderID ) ranknoequal ,    RANK()
>   OVER (PARTITION BY as1.SalesOrderID ORDER BY as1.OrderQty ) rank_orderqty
>   FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail as1 WHERE SalesOrderId = 43659 ORDER BY
>   OrderQty;

Gives:

SalesOrderID    OrderQty    rank_salesorderid   rank_orderqty
43659   1   1   1
43659   1   1   1
43659   1   1   1
43659   1   1   1
43659   1   1   1
43659   1   1   1
43659   2   1   7
43659   2   1   7
43659   3   1   9
43659   3   1   9
43659   4   1   11
43659   6   1   12

Notice how the Rank changes when we use OrderQty (rightmost column second table) in ORDER BY and how it changes when we use SalesOrderDetailID (rightmost column first table) in ORDER BY.