# SQL Server 2008 How can I SELECT rows with Value by GROUP(ing) other column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi guys I'm a beginner at SQL so please bear with me.. :)

My question is as follows.

I got this table:

```
     DateTime         ID     Year    Month   Value    Cost
-------------------|------|--------|-------|-------|--------|
 1-1-2013 00:00:01 |  1   |  2013  |   1   |  30   |   90   |
 1-1-2013 00:01:01 |  1   |  2013  |   1   |  0    |   0    |
 1-1-2013 00:02:01 |  1   |  2013  |   1   |  1    |   3    |
 1-2-2013 00:00:01 |  1   |  2013  |   2   |  2    |   6    |
 1-2-2013 00:01:01 |  1   |  2013  |   2   |  3    |   9    |
 1-2-2013 00:02:01 |  1   |  2013  |   2   |  4    |   12   |
 1-3-2013 00:00:01 |  1   |  2013  |   3   |  5    |   15   |
 1-3-2013 00:01:01 |  1   |  2013  |   3   |  6    |   18   |
 1-3-2013 00:02:01 |  1   |  2013  |   3   |  7    |   21   |
```

Now what I'm trying to get is this result

```
   Year    Month   Value    Cost
|--------|-------|-------|--------|
|  2013  |   1   |  1    |   3    |
|  2013  |   2   |  4    |   12   |
|  2013  |   3   |  7    |   21   |
```

As you can see I'm trying to GROUP BY the [Month] and the [Year] and to get the last [Value] for every [Month].

Now as you can understand from the result I do not try to get the MAX() value from the [Value] column but the last value for every [Month] and that is my issue..

Thanks in advance

PS
I was able to GROUP BY the [Year] and the [Month] but as I understand that when I adding the [Value] column the GROUP BY is not effecting the result, as the SQL need more spcification on the value you what the SQL to get..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the result:

```
select year, month, value, cost
from
(
  select year, month, value, cost,
    row_number() over(partition by year, month order by datetime desc) rn
  from yourtable
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aecd2/4)

Or you can use a subquery to get this (*note:* with this version if you have more than one record with the same max `datetime` per month then you will return each record:

```
select t1.year, t1.month, t1.value, t1.cost
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(datetime) datetime
  from yourtable
  group by year, month
) t2
  on t1.datetime = t2.datetime
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aecd2/6)

Both give the same result:

```
| YEAR | MONTH | VALUE | COST |
-------------------------------
| 2013 |     1 |     1 |    3 |
| 2013 |     2 |     4 |   12 |
| 2013 |     3 |     7 |   21 |
```

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful, I used u'r first sample and I got exact what I needed. cheers m8.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `row_number()`, you can also use `rank()`. Using `rank()` might give you multiple values within the same year and month, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747327/sql-rank-versus-row-number).
Because of this, a group by is added.

```
SELECT
  [Year],
  [Month],
  [Value],
  [Cost]
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    [Year],
    [Month],
    [Value],
    [Cost],
    Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY [Year], [Month] ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) AS [Rank]
  FROM [t1]
) AS [sub]
WHERE [Rank] = 1
GROUP BY 
  [Year],
  [Month],
  [Value],
  [Cost]
ORDER BY
  [Year] ASC,
  [Month] ASC
```

As stated in the comments, this might still return multiple records for a single month. Therefor the ORDER BY statement can be extended, based on the desired functionality:

```
Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY [Year], [Month] ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC, [Value] DESC, [Cost] ASC) AS [Rank]
```

Switching the order of `[Value]` and `[Cost]` or `ASC` <> `DESC` will influence the rank and because of that the result.

Comment: I was trying that script and the result logic is as I needed but now I can see that when I've more then one max time stampes at [DateTime] I'm getting all of them, when I need just one.
What can I do to fix that?

Comment: I see what you mean. You'll have to extend the ORDER BY used for ranking. Depending on what suits you best. I'll expand my answer in a moment.

Comment: THX m8, but I got the "V" mark to @bluefeet as his first example was giving me the exact logic I searched for and the performance are suited for me. Cheers.

Comment: If not already, do have a look at the post mentioned in my answer. It is wise to extend the ORDER BY, so you know exactly how the rownumber or rank is determined. Only ordering by [DateTime] leaves a small factor of randomness.

Comment: Yes I did saw it, and I've tried u'r fix too, It works. I agree with u about how to determine "what goes where" in the rownumber or rank window, so I'll refactor my script as of that. THX again. (If it was possible I was giving u the "V" mark too ;))