# Delete duplicate rows keeping the first row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates, sql-delete

How can I **delete duplicate rows** where no `unique row id` exists?

My table is

```
col1  col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
john  1    1    1    1    1    1 
john  1    1    1    1    1    1
sally 2    2    2    2    2    2
sally 2    2    2    2    2    2
```

I want to be left with the following after the duplicate removal:

```
john  1    1    1    1    1    1
sally 2    2    2    2    2    2
```

I've tried a few queries but I think they depend on having a row id as I don't get the desired result. For example:

```
DELETE
FROM table
WHERE col1 IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING (COUNT(col1) > 1)
)
```

Comment: This is not a dupe of the first link.  In this question there is no row ID and in the linked question there is a row ID.  Very different.

Comment: change 'SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY id HAVING' to have aggregated function e.g. MAX/MIN and it should work.

Answer (score 991):

I like CTEs and `ROW_NUMBER` as the two combined allow us to see which rows are deleted (or updated), therefore just change the `DELETE FROM CTE...` to `SELECT * FROM CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1)
   FROM dbo.Table1
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/ZHFH51082)</kbd>  (result is different; I assume that it's due to a typo on your part)

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5    COL6    COL7
john    1        1       1       1       1       1
sally   2        2       2       2       2       2
```

This example determines duplicates by a single column `col1` because of the `PARTITION BY col1`. If you want to include multiple columns simply add them to the `PARTITION BY`:

```
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, ... ORDER BY OrderColumn)
```

Comment: @Tim Great answer. what about if you would want to only delete the duplicate for john. where would the 'WHERE' statement go ?. Just curious

Comment: @omachu23:  in this case it doesn't matter, although i think that it is more efficient in the CTE than outside(`AND COl1='John'`). Normally you should apply the filter in the CTE.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  I put the (AND Col1='Jhon') after WHERE RN  >1 and it worked !. Because i didnt know where to put it inside CTE. It kept giving me errors. Anyways Thanks for the answer ! Awsome work !

Comment: @omachu23: you can use any SQL in the CTE(apart from ordering), so if you want to filter by Johns: `...FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE Col1='John'`. Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fae73/744/0

Comment: The easiest solution may just be `set rowcount 1 delete from t1 where col1=1 and col2=1` as seen [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/139444)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Can please help me for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065340/sql-server-2008-r2-delete-duplicate-rows-from-tables-containing-in-view/32065972?noredirect=1#comment52032907_32065972

Comment: This answer will only delete the rows that has duplicates in col1. Add the columns in the "select" to "partition by", for example using the select in the answer: RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7 ORDER BY col1)

Comment: This helped more than 5 times, always coming back for this CTE hahahaha

Hope I have that in my mind now

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does CTE mean I get sql errors when I put that in.

Comment: Please make a backup before running this query ... Or you might regret it.

Comment: What's the point of selecting all those different columns? Since you are only deleting by `col1`, why not just `SELECT [col1], RN = ...` ?

Comment: @minseong the example should be using all the same columns. You can see that if you click the demo link.

Comment: @Whitecat CTE stands for COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION

Comment: @Whitecat You'll get an error on MariaDB/MySQL. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799157/use-a-cte-to-update-or-delete-in-mysql

Answer (score 207):

I would prefer CTE for deleting duplicate rows from sql server table

Strongly recommend following [this article](https://medium.com/@CodAffection/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server-3791ba275645).

> by keeping original

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3 ORDER BY col1,col2,col3) AS RN
FROM MyTable
)
 
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1
```

> without keeping original

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT *,R=RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col1,col2,col3)
FROM MyTable)
 
DELETE CTE
WHERE R IN (SELECT R FROM CTE GROUP BY R HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Comment: I am little confused. You deleted it from CTE not the original table. So how does it work?

Comment: @Bigeyes deleting records from CTE will remove corresponding records from actual physical table.(because CTE contains reference to actual records).

Comment: Why would you want to delete both the original and its duplicate? I'm not understanding why you wouldn't want to just remove the duplicate and keep the other.

Comment: ERROR:  relation "cte" does not exist

Comment: @Rich I wanted to delete original and duplicate in a development environment in order to re-run a process until I was satisfied with it. This was faster than coding in transaction rollbacks or backing up and restoring the database in my use case.

Comment: @ShamseerK How does T-SQL determine which one is original? I am using "by keeping original".

Answer (score 86):

Without using `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()` you can just delete the records just by using group by with `MAX` function here is an example

```
DELETE
FROM MyDuplicateTable
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM MyDuplicateTable
GROUP BY DuplicateColumn1, DuplicateColumn2, DuplicateColumn3)
```

Comment: This query will delete non-duplicate records.

Comment: This works fine, thank you. @DerekSmalls this not remove my non-duplicate records.

Comment: Or you can keep the original records using `MIN(ID)`

Comment: While this may work in lots of situation, the question clearly states there is no unique id.

Comment: select max (id) will also return the non-duplicated records. so excluding these ID from delete will work fine I think.

Comment: does this delete some portion of MyDuplicateTable?

Comment: Be carefully, this is a very slow solution in multiple fields of GROUP BY part with millions rows.

Answer (score 37):

If you have no references, like foreign keys, you can do this.  I do it a lot when testing proofs of concept and the test data gets duplicated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [col1],[col2],[col3],[col4],[col5],[col6],[col7]

INTO [newTable]

FROM [oldTable]
```

Go into the object explorer and delete the old table.

Rename the new table with the old table's name.

Comment: This is the simplest way that I learned in my intro materials, and which I use.

Comment: Curious how this answer could perform well when [oldTable] has billions of rows...

Comment: This will burn the TBW on Solid State Drives, not recommended.

Comment: Also note that permissions on the table will be lost, when doing a RENAME

Answer (score 24):

## Remove all duplicates, but the very first ones (with min ID)

should work equally in other SQL servers, like Postgres:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (
   select min(id) from table
   group by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
)
```

Comment: what is 'id' column? There is no 'id' in the OP's dataset

Comment: @SergeMerzliakov, it's a primary key of the row. This answer should not work when there is no unique key... However, most of the readers, in the general case, have it, so `id` should make sense for them.

Comment: You can also use the automatically generated `ctid` PostgreSQL row identifier even if an explicit `id` column is not present: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626481/rowid-equivalent-in-postgres-9-2 In SQLite it's called `rowid`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190541/deleting-duplicate-rows-from-sqlite-database

Answer (score 18):

```
DELETE from search
where id not in (
   select min(id) from search
   group by url
   having count(*)=1

   union

   SELECT min(id) FROM search
   group by url
   having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Couldn't you re-write to: where id in (select max(id) ... having count(*) > 1) ?

Comment: I don't believe there's any need to use having or union, this will suffice: delete from search where id not in (select min(id) from search  group by url)

Answer (score 16):

There are two solutions in `mysql`:

**A)** Delete duplicate rows using ***`DELETE JOIN`*** statement

```
DELETE t1 FROM contacts t1
INNER JOIN contacts t2 
WHERE 
    t1.id < t2.id AND 
    t1.email = t2.email;
```

This query references the contacts table twice, therefore, it uses the table alias `t1` and `t2`.

The output is:

> 1
>   Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.10 sec)

In case you want to delete duplicate rows and keep the `lowest id`, you can use the following statement:

```
DELETE c1 FROM contacts c1
INNER JOIN contacts c2 
WHERE
    c1.id > c2.id AND 
    c1.email = c2.email;
```

**B)** Delete duplicate rows using an intermediate table

The following shows the steps for removing duplicate rows using an intermediate table:

1. Create a new table with the structure the same as the original table that you want to delete duplicate rows.

2. Insert distinct rows from the original table to the immediate table.

3. Insert distinct rows from the original table to the immediate table.

Step 1. Create a new table whose structure is the same as the original table:

```
CREATE TABLE source_copy LIKE source;
```

Step 2. Insert distinct rows from the original table to the new table:

```
INSERT INTO source_copy
SELECT * FROM source
GROUP BY col; -- column that has duplicate values
```

Step 3. drop the original table and rename the immediate table to the original one

```
DROP TABLE source;
ALTER TABLE source_copy RENAME TO source;
```

Source: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/

Comment: I have around 190000 rows in my table.
sol 1 is not a good choice for this many numbers of rows.
sol 2 works well for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Please see the below way of deletion too.

```
Declare @table table
(col1 varchar(10),col2 int,col3 int, col4 int, col5 int, col6 int, col7 int)
Insert into @table values 
('john',1,1,1,1,1,1),
('john',1,1,1,1,1,1),
('sally',2,2,2,2,2,2),
('sally',2,2,2,2,2,2)
```

Created a sample table named `@table` and loaded it with given data.

[image]

```
Delete  aliasName from (
Select  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7 order by col1) as rowNumber
From    @table) aliasName 
Where   rowNumber > 1

Select * from @table
```

[image]

Note: If you are giving all columns in the `Partition by` part, then `order by` do not have much significance.

*I know, the question is asked three years ago, and my answer is another version of what Tim has posted, But posting just incase it is helpful for anyone.*

Comment: this one is more reliable

Answer (score 10):

To delete the duplicate rows from the table in SQL Server, you follow these steps:

1. Find duplicate rows using GROUP BY clause or ROW_NUMBER() function.
2. Use DELETE statement to remove the duplicate rows.

**Setting up a sample table**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts;

CREATE TABLE contacts(
    contact_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);
```

**Insert values**

```
INSERT INTO contacts
    (first_name,last_name,email) 
VALUES
    ('Syed','Abbas','syed.abbas@example.com'),
    ('Catherine','Abel','catherine.abel@example.com'),
    ('Kim','Abercrombie','kim.abercrombie@example.com'),
    ('Kim','Abercrombie','kim.abercrombie@example.com'),
    ('Kim','Abercrombie','kim.abercrombie@example.com'),
    ('Hazem','Abolrous','hazem.abolrous@example.com'),
    ('Hazem','Abolrous','hazem.abolrous@example.com'),
    ('Humberto','Acevedo','humberto.acevedo@example.com'),
    ('Humberto','Acevedo','humberto.acevedo@example.com'),
    ('Pilar','Ackerman','pilar.ackerman@example.com');
```

[image]

**Query**

```
    SELECT 
   contact_id, 
   first_name, 
   last_name, 
   email
FROM 
   contacts;
```

**Delete duplicate rows from a table**

```
   WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        contact_id, 
        first_name, 
        last_name, 
        email, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                first_name, 
                last_name, 
                email
            ORDER BY 
                first_name, 
                last_name, 
                email
        ) row_num
     FROM 
        contacts
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1;
```

Should delete the record now

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It can be done by many ways in sql server
the most simplest way to do so is:
Insert the distinct rows from the duplicate rows table to new temporary table. Then delete all the data from duplicate rows  table then insert all data from temporary table which has no duplicates as shown below.

```
select distinct * into #tmp From table
   delete from table
   insert into table
   select * from #tmp drop table #tmp

   select * from table
```

Delete duplicate rows using Common Table Expression(CTE)

```
With CTE_Duplicates as 
(select id,name , row_number() 
over(partition by id,name order by id,name ) rownumber  from table  ) 
delete from CTE_Duplicates where rownumber!=1
```

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft has a vey ry neat guide on how to remove duplicates. Check out  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444

In brief, here is the easiest way to delete duplicates when you have just a few rows to delete:

```
SET rowcount 1;
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE myprimarykey=1;
```

*myprimarykey* is the identifier for the row.

I set `rowcount` to 1 because I only had two rows that were duplicated. If I had had 3 rows duplicated then I would have set *rowcount* to 2 so that it deletes the first two that it sees and only leaves one in table t1.

Comment: How do i know how many rows i have duplicated if i have 10k rows?

Comment: @Fearghal try "select primaryKey, count(*) from myTable group by primaryKey;"

Comment: But what if there are varying numbers of duplicate rows? ie row a has 2 records and row b has 5 records and row c has no duplicate records

Comment: @user2070775 What if only a subset of all the rows have duplicates, and of those duplicates some are duplicated twice and some three or four times?

Comment: @user2070775 I missed the part where you said "just a few rows to delete". Also there is a warning on the page about set rowcount that in future versions of sql it wont affect update or delete statements

Comment: @thermite in that case, I guess it would be more convinient to write a script and not trying to do it manually in SQL. The script would select the duplicated rows, count the number of duplicates and execute "SET rowcount $numer_of_dulicated-1;
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE myprimarykey=$duplicated_id_value;"

Answer (score 6):

Try to Use:

```
SELECT linkorder
    ,Row_Number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY linkorder ORDER BY linkorder DESC
        ) AS RowNum
FROM u_links
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
with myCTE
as

(
select productName,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY productName order by slno) as Duplicate from productDetails
)
Delete from myCTE where Duplicate>1
```

Comment: Works great and in a flash in over millions of records

Answer (score 4):

After trying the suggested solution above, that works for small medium tables. 
I can suggest that solution for very large tables. since it runs in iterations.

1. Drop all dependency views of the `LargeSourceTable`
2. you can find the dependecies by using sql managment studio, right click on the table and click "View Dependencies"
3. Rename the table:
4. `sp_rename 'LargeSourceTable', 'LargeSourceTable_Temp'; GO`
5. Create the `LargeSourceTable` again, but now, add a primary key with all the columns that define the duplications add `WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)`
6. For example:

   `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LargeSourceTable]
       (
           ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
           [CreateDate]        DATETIME CONSTRAINT [DF_LargeSourceTable_CreateDate] DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
           [Column1]    CHAR (36)      NOT NULL,
           [Column2]  NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
           [Column3]        CHAR (36)      NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY (Column1, Column2) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
       );
       GO`
7. Create again the views that you dropped in the first place for the new created table
8. Now, Run the following sql script, you will see the results in 1,000,000 rows per page, you can change the row number per page to see the results more often.
9. Note, that I set the `IDENTITY_INSERT` on and off because one the columns contains auto incremental id, which I'm also copying

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT LargeSourceTable ON
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT, @RowspPage AS INT
DECLARE @TotalRows AS INT 
declare @dt varchar(19)
SET @PageNumber = 0
SET @RowspPage = 1000000`

`select @TotalRows = count (*) from LargeSourceTable_TEMP`

```
While ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage < @TotalRows )
Begin
    begin transaction tran_inner
        ; with cte as
        (
            SELECT * FROM LargeSourceTable_TEMP ORDER BY ID
            OFFSET ((@PageNumber) * @RowspPage) ROWS
            FETCH NEXT @RowspPage ROWS ONLY
        )

        INSERT INTO LargeSourceTable 
        (
             ID                     
            ,[CreateDate]       
            ,[Column1]   
            ,[Column2] 
            ,[Column3]       
        )       
        select 
             ID                     
            ,[CreateDate]       
            ,[Column1]   
            ,[Column2] 
            ,[Column3]       
        from cte

    commit transaction tran_inner

    PRINT 'Page: ' + convert(varchar(10), @PageNumber)
    PRINT 'Transfered: ' + convert(varchar(20), @PageNumber * @RowspPage)
    PRINT 'Of: ' + convert(varchar(20), @TotalRows)

    SELECT @dt = convert(varchar(19), getdate(), 121)
    RAISERROR('Inserted on: %s', 0, 1, @dt) WITH NOWAIT
    SET @PageNumber = @PageNumber + 1
End
```

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT LargeSourceTable OFF`

Answer (score 2):

```
-- this query will keep only one instance of a duplicate record.
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3-- based on what? --can be multiple columns
                                       ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
         FROM   Mytable)



delete  FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by the duplicate records according to the field(s), then hold one of the records and delete the rest.
For example:

```
DELETE prg.Person WHERE Id IN (
SELECT dublicateRow.Id FROM
(
select MIN(Id) MinId, NationalCode
 from  prg.Person group by NationalCode  having count(NationalCode ) > 1
 ) GroupSelect
 JOIN  prg.Person dublicateRow ON dublicateRow.NationalCode = GroupSelect.NationalCode 
 WHERE dublicateRow.Id <> GroupSelect.MinId)
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting duplicates from a huge(several millions of records) table might take long time . I suggest that you do a bulk insert into a temp table of the selected rows rather than deleting.

```
--REWRITING YOUR CODE(TAKE NOTE OF THE 3RD LINE) WITH CTE AS(SELECT NAME,ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) ID FROM @TB) SELECT * INTO #unique_records FROM 
CTE WHERE ID =1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help in your case

```
DELETE t1 FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

Comment: Since there is no id in the tables in the original question; I don't think this will actually solve the issue.

Comment: If you read the question carefully, you'll find `id` in that.

Answer (score 2):

To delete duplicate rows in SQL Server where no unique row ID exists, you can use the ROW_NUMBER() function in combination with a common table expression (CTE) to identify and delete the duplicate rows. Here's an example query that should achieve the desired result:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7 ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RowNumber
    FROM YourTable
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RowNumber > 1;
```

Replace YourTable with the actual name of your table. This query assigns a row number to each row within each set of duplicate rows based on the combination of values in col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, and col7. The rows with a row number greater than 1 are then deleted.

You can leverage [dbForge Studio's](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/) SQL editor to execute the query and efficiently handle various other database management tasks.

Answer (score 1):

[With reference to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/139444/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-table-in-sql-server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/139444/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-table-in-sql-server)

The idea of removing duplicate involves

- a) Protecting those rows that are not duplicate
- b) Retain one of the many rows that qualified together as duplicate.

Step-by-step

- 1) First identify the rows those satisfy the definition of duplicate
  and insert them into temp table, say #tableAll .
- 2) Select non-duplicate(single-rows) or distinct rows into temp table
  say #tableUnique.
- 3) Delete from source table joining #tableAll to delete the
  duplicates.
- 4) Insert into source table all the rows from #tableUnique.
- 5) Drop #tableAll and #tableUnique

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to add a column to the table temporarily, this was a solution that worked for me:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DUPPEDTABLE ADD RowID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Then perform a DELETE using a combination of MIN and GROUP BY

```
DELETE b
FROM dbo.DUPPEDTABLE b
WHERE b.RowID NOT IN (
                     SELECT MIN(RowID) AS RowID
                     FROM dbo.DUPPEDTABLE a WITH (NOLOCK)
                     GROUP BY a.ITEM_NUMBER,
                              a.CHARACTERISTIC,
                              a.INTVALUE,
                              a.FLOATVALUE,
                              a.STRINGVALUE
                 );
```

Verify that the DELETE performed correctly:

```
SELECT a.ITEM_NUMBER,
    a.CHARACTERISTIC,
    a.INTVALUE,
    a.FLOATVALUE,
    a.STRINGVALUE, COUNT(*)--MIN(RowID) AS RowID
FROM dbo.DUPPEDTABLE a WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY a.ITEM_NUMBER,
    a.CHARACTERISTIC,
    a.INTVALUE,
    a.FLOATVALUE,
    a.STRINGVALUE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

The result should have no rows with a count greater than 1.  Finally, remove the rowid column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DUPPEDTABLE DROP COLUMN RowID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh wow, i feel so stupid by ready all this answers, they are like experts' answer with all CTE and temp table and etc.

And all I did to get it working was simply aggregated the ID column by using MAX.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE col1 IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM table GROUP BY id HAVING ( COUNT(col1) > 1 )
)
```

NOTE: you might need to run it multiple time to remove duplicate as this will only delete one set of duplicate rows at a time.

Comment: This will not work since it'll remove all duplicates without leaving the originals. OP is asking to preserve the original records.

Comment: Not true, max will give you max ID that satisfy having condition. If that is not true, prove your case for down vote.

Answer (score 1):

please simply add the keyword DISTINCT right after the SELECT command,
for example:

```
SELECT DISTICNT ColumnOne, ColumnTwo, ColumnThree
 FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicates from Azure SQL server

```
DELETE T
FROM
(
SELECT *
, DupRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY key_value
              ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
            )
FROM original_table
) AS T
WHERE DupRank > 1
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/development/remove-duplicate-rows-sql-server-tab#method-2

Answer (score 0):

Another way of removing dublicated rows without loosing information in one step is like following:

```
delete from dublicated_table t1 (nolock)
join (
    select t2.dublicated_field
    , min(len(t2.field_kept)) as min_field_kept
    from dublicated_table t2 (nolock)
    group by t2.dublicated_field having COUNT(*)>1
) t3 
on t1.dublicated_field=t3.dublicated_field 
    and len(t1.field_kept)=t3.min_field_kept
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TB TABLE(NAME VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @TB VALUES ('Red'),('Red'),('Green'),('Blue'),('White'),('White')
--**Delete by Rank**
;WITH CTE AS(SELECT NAME,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NEWID()) ID FROM @TB)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE ID>1
SELECT NAME FROM @TB;
--**Delete by Row Number** 
;WITH CTE AS(SELECT NAME,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) ID FROM @TB)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE ID>1;
SELECT NAME FROM @TB;
```

Comment: Deleting duplicates from a huge(several millions of records) table might take long time . I suggest that you do a bulk insert into a temp table of the selected rows rather deleting. 
'--REWRITING YOUR CODE(TAKE NOTE OF THE 3RD LINE)
WITH CTE AS(SELECT NAME,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) ID FROM @TB)
SELECT * INTO #unique_records FROM CTE WHERE ID =1;'

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM TBL1  WHERE ID  IN
(SELECT ID FROM TBL1  a WHERE ID!=
(select MAX(ID) from TBL1  where DUPVAL=a.DUPVAL 
group by DUPVAL
having count(DUPVAL)>1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE p1 FROM Person p1,
    Person p2
WHERE
    p1.Email = p2.Email AND p1.Id > p2.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

the newly replaced table will have only the distinct record,

**Case: when you don't have a foreign key and data was duplicate as all the columns**

```
create or replace table table_x  as select distinct * from table_x;
```