# Deleting duplicates based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have listed duplicates using the following:

```
select s.MessageId, t.* 
from Message s
join (
    select ToUserId, FromUserId, count(*) as qty
    from Message
    group by ToUserId, FromUserId
    having count(*) > 1
) t on s.ToUserId = t.ToUserId and s.FromUserId = t.FromUserId
```

Now, how do I delete all but one of the Messages (I'm trying to remove duplicates so I can apply a unique index on `FromUserId and ToUserId`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicate rows (based on values from multiple columns) from SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243945/removing-duplicate-rows-based-on-values-from-multiple-columns-from-sql-table)

Comment: @FuzzyTree why would you vote to close if there are already useful answers?

Comment: Because it's still a duplicate question and duplicate questions clutter the website without providing any value to future visitors

Comment: @FuzzyTree look at the link you provided.  Both the question and answer are muddled.  Duplicate intentions doesn't equate to duplicate results - we have a more accessible resource here now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a [`cte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and assign row numbers so that all but one for duplicate pairs can be deleted.

```
with rownums as 
(select m.*, 
 row_number() over(partition by ToUserId, FromUserId order by ToUserId, FromUserId) as rnum
 from Message m)
delete r
from rownums r
where rnum > 1
```

Comment: We can also use DENSE_RANK() instead of ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sample data**

```
    DECLARE @Message TABLE(ID INT ,ToUserId varchar(100),FromUserId varchar(100))
    INSERT INTO @Message(ID,ToUserId, FromUserId )
    VALUES  ( 1,'abc',  'def'  ), ( 2,'abc',  'def'  ), ( 3,'abc',  'def'  ), ( 4,'qaz',  'xsw'  )
```

**--Do delete data**

```
    DELETE m FROM @Message AS m 
    INNER JOIN (
         SELECT *,row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY ToUserId,FromUserId ORDER BY ID ) AS rn FROM @Message AS m
    ) t ON t.ID=m.ID
    WHERE t.rn>1

    SELECT * FROM @Message
```

```
----------- ---------- ----------
1           abc        def
4           qaz        xsw
```

If there is no column to indicate specify line as ID, you can try to use address of line (for example %%lockres%%)

```
    DELETE m FROM @Message AS m 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT *,row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY ToUserId,FromUserId ORDER BY %%lockres%% ) AS rn FROM @Message AS m
    ) t ON t.ID=m.ID
    WHERE t.rn>1

    SELECT *, %%lockres%% FROM @Message
```