# Drop duplicates based on Two distinct column values in snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to delete the duplicate rows based on two columns. An example for table as below

Table Name as REFF_TABLE

```
LOCATIONID  TICKER  ROW_KEY
AB            PA    201605
AB            PA    201605
AB            PA    201606
AB            PA    201606
DA            PB    201705
DA            PB    201706
DA            PB    201707
DE            PC    201808
DE            PC    201809
```

I want to remove duplicates rows by considering two columns - LOCATIONID, TICKER . Here need to take maximum value of ROW_KEY

Final output table as below

```
LOCATIONID  TICKER  ROW_KEY
AB            PA    201606
DA            PB    201707
DE            PC    201809
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: What have you tries so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hope this post from 2015 on StackOverflow helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243945/removing-duplicate-rows-based-on-values-from-multiple-columns-from-sql-table/30244183

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical SQL `GROUP BY` should be enough:

```sql
select locationid, ticker, max(row_key) row_key
from table
group by locationid, ticker
```