# Delete duplicate records using a concatenated column in TSQL table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-delete

I have a table where unique records can be identified using a concatenation of ORDER and ITEM, like so:

| ORDER | ITEM |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 001 |
| 1234 | 002 |
| 1235 | 001 |
| 1235 | 002 |
| 1235 | 003 |
| 1236 | 001 |
| 1237 | 001 |
| ... | ... |

The table currently has duplicates of each unique combination, like so:

| ORDER | ITEM |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 001 |
| 1234 | 002 |
| 1235 | 001 |
| 1235 | 002 |
| 1235 | 003 |
| 1236 | 001 |
| 1237 | 001 |
| 1234 | 001 |
| 1234 | 002 |
| 1235 | 001 |
| 1235 | 002 |
| 1235 | 003 |
| 1236 | 001 |
| 1237 | 001 |
| ... | ... |

I'm using the following subquery to select all duplicate rows:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT order + item AS ID,
    Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY order, item ORDER BY order) as CN
    FROM [schema].[table]
    ) 
AS Q WHERE Q.CN > 1
```

With the result:

| ID | CN |
| --- | --- |
| 1234001 | 2 |
| 1234001 | 3 |
| 1234001 | 4 |
| 1234002 | 2 |
| 1234002 | 3 |
| 1234002 | 4 |
| 1235001 | 2 |
| 1235001 | 3 |
| 1235001 | 4 |
| ... | ... |

Forgive me if this is a very simple question, but is there a simple modification to turn the above subquery into a delete statement and remove every record it currentlyt selects (i.e. with CN > 1)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30244183/2055998

Comment: the table only has those 2 columns? if that is the case, you dont need to delete anything, instead, using `SELECT DISTINCT [Order], [ITEM] FROM table`, if there exists the other columns, you need to take into the consideration which row should be kept when there is more than 1 row returned for that pair.

Comment: If records are unique based on these values, why isn't there a constraint on the table for this?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, there are, indeed, other columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below to delete duplicate record

```
DELETE FROM [schema].[table]
WHERE order + item IN (
    SELECT order + item
    FROM [schema].[table]
    GROUP BY order, item
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: A simple solution, indeed -- thank you.  I'm sorry to ask this, but I fearI shouldn't have shared the table name, so I changed it to a generic [schema].[table] name in the initial question.  Would you mind making this small revision so it reflects accurately?  Thank you in advance, and apologies for this oversight.

Answer (score 2):

also you can use self join like :

```
DELETE t1 FROM [schema].[table] t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT order, item
    FROM [schema].[table]
    GROUP BY order, item
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) t2 ON t1.order = t2.order AND t1.item = t2.item;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your subquery with a `CTE` to get the duplicated records, then a simple delete with where clause cn > 1

```
with cte as (
    SELECT _order, item,
    Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY _order, item ORDER BY _order) as CN
    FROM mytable
)
Delete from cte WHERE cn > 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/CIgYLzm1)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.  I accepted another answer but I will likely use this.  Again, thank you.