# Insert of data in a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Product`:

```
Name       Description
----------------------
  x            1
  y            2
  z            3
```

I have another table `Producttemp`:

```
Name   Description
------------------
  x         1
  x         1
  x         2
  r         3
  r         3
  z         8
  z         8
```

I need to insert data from `Producttemp` into `Product` and only that data which is in combination of `Name` and `Description`.

So as of now `x,1` should not be inserted because this combination already exists in `Product` table and only `(r,1)` and `(z,8)` should be inserted and we don't have to insert the duplicate combinations.

I am trying with this query :

```
create table #vhf (pk_id numeric)

INSERT INTO product (product_name, product_description)
OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO #vhf
    SELECT  
        temp.product_name,
        temp.product_description
    FROM 
        producttemp
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT distinct temp.product_name FROM product prj, product temp 
                    WHERE temp.product_description = prj.product_description 
                      AND temp.product_name = prj.product_name)
```

This query is returning all the values that are not there in product table but it is also inserting the duplicate rows

Comment: Please check your question and fix typos. There is no `(r,1)` in the example. On the other hand, there is `(x,2)` in the example, why you don't want to insert that combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
INSERT INTO [Product]
SELECT  DISTINCT PT.[Name],PT.[Description]
FROM    [Producttemp] AS PT
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Product] AS P ON P.[Name] = PT.[Name] 
       AND P.[Description] = PT.[Description]
WHERE   P.[Name] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt to de-dupe is completely wrong.

Do it like this:

```
...
SELECT  pt.product_name,
        pt.product_description
FROM producttemp pt
where  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product prj
 where pt.product_description=prj.product_description 
 and pt.product_name=prj.product_name
)
```

Comment: Even then I am getting duplicates from my temporary table

Comment: If the table `ProductTemp` has duplicates in it, then you should de-dupe it prior to running this step.   There are lots of examples of de-duping a table already on SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood you do not want to insert rows from '**Producttemp**' that are already in '**Product**'.

For this you can use **MERGE**

```
MERGE Product AS P
USING(SELECT DISTINCT Name,Descrip FROM Producttemp) AS PT
ON  P.Name = PT.Name AND P.Descrip=PT.Descrip
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT(Name,Descrip) VALUES(PT.Name,PT.Descrip);
```