# Delete duplicate records in my sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to delete duplicate or more than duplicate record in my table using this :

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT distinct LineNumber FROM SPMS.dbo.Lines
DECLARE @lineNumber VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @lineId int;
DECLARE @count int;
   OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT 
   FROM db_cursor 
   INTO @lineNumber;
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
  BEGIN  
    SELECT @count=count(*) 
      FROM [SPMS].[dbo].Lines 
     WHERE @lineNumber=@lineNumber
           if @count>1
    BEGIN   
    SELECT @lineId=Id 
      FROM [SPMS].[dbo].Lines 
     WHERE @lineNumber=@lineNumber
    DELETE FROM [SPMS].[dbo].Lines 
     WHERE id=@lineId 
       END
FETCH NEXT 
      FROM db_cursor INTO @lineNumber;
       END;
     CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

But it delete all same records .why ?

Comment: You can do this using a simple CTE and a `DELETE` statement - no need to involve cursors, etc. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18390574/15498)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is it ?WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT LineNumber,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY LineNumber ORDER BY LineNumber)
   FROM  [SPMS].[dbo].[Lines]
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it works thank you .i just run the above query .

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you can answer the question .

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever should i delete the question ?

Comment: I think it's fine to exist as a duplicate.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ok thank you