# delete distinct by column sQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete min Id if there is multiple employeeId. How can i do that in sQL query? Attacted my SQL query result

```
delete @CompPayDetEE where exists (select 1 from @CompPayDetEE group by AppEmployeeId )
```

[image: SQL Result]

Comment: You write code. That's your job, we (maybe) try help fix whatever you end up writing.

Comment: please paste data as text and show expected result...sample sql fiddle will help a lot

Comment: attached the image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I am retaining all max ids and deleting the remaining rows:

```
DELETE FROM Yourtable
  WHERE id NOT IN 
        (
          SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM Yourtable
           GROUP BY AppEmployeeID
         );
```

Comment: This should work... I am retaining all max ids and deleting the remaining rows....

Answer (score 0):

```
declare  @Table table(ID int, EmployID varchar(10), TaxAmount int, TaxableAmount int)
insert into @Table values
(1, '1',    1,      0)
,(2, '1',    13,     1)
,(3, '3',    52,     4)


WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployID ORDER BY id desc) as RN
    FROM @Table
)
DELETE cte
 WHERE RN <> 1;

SELECT * from @Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete @CompPayDetEE
where Id in(    select IdToDelete = min(Id)
                from @CompPayDetEE
                group by AppEmployeeId
                having count(*)>1)
```