# SQL - How to select A&B results excluding B&A redundent results from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

You have a table containing a userID column and 2 function columns.
*The table has 100 million rows and 10's of thousands of users.*

[image]

The problem is that each user has their function1 and function2 duplicated but in the opposite function order. I.E. User=1000 has F1=5, F2=10 but also F2=10, F2=5. So if you can filter off these duplicates you can save about 50% of the space this table is using.

What is the **fastest** way to filter out the duplicate functions for each user.

Comment: tag one dbms you are actually using.

Comment: Surly you don't need a solution for MySql, Sql-Server and Sqlite... Please tag **only** the relevant rdbms, and add the specific version tag as well.

Comment: Is it necessary to have mirrored data in the table? I'd delete one of each and then put a primary key on the UserID. That way you'll avoid similar situations in the future.

Comment: @daZza No its not necessary to have mirrored data.

Comment: @Zohar Peled no, but i was willing to port the data to any of those if a solution presented itself. I mainly use SqlServer 2008r2 and 2014

Comment: You want to remove duplicates or what?

Comment: @Sami Yes, the idea is to shrink the table by removing the duplicate function access for each user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicate rows in sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Sami It's not really a duplicate of this question, but there problaby is an answer to this exact one as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, @TriV's answer is correct, as I read the question.  I have no idea why it is downvoted or deleted.

Second, if you want to remove the rows *and* you know all are duplicated, then you can do:

```
delete from t
    where function1 > function2;
```

That is not satisfying, because you want the fastest method.  Deletion can be expensive, so it might be faster to:

```
select *
into temp_t
from t
where function1 < function2;

truncate table t;

insert into t
    select *
    from temp_t;
```

If you don't have full duplicates, then you can do the same idea with something like:

```
select *
into temp_t
from t
where function1 < function2
union all
select *
from t t
where function1 > function2 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.function1 = t.function2 and t2.function2 = t.function1);
```

The latter expression is probably the fastest way to get the unique set, assuming you have an index on `t(function1, function2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number` to get one such combination for a user in case (a,b) , (b,a) pairs exist.

```
select userid,function1,function2 from (
select userid,function1,function2
,row_number() over(partition by userid
                   order by 
                   case when function1<function2 then function1 else function2 end,
                   case when function1>function2 then function1 else function2 end,
                   function1
                  ) as rnum
from tablename
) t
where rnum=1
```

Use a cte to delete one of the symmetric pair combinations.

```
with cte as (select userid,function1,function2
             ,row_number() over(partition by userid
                   order by 
                   case when function1<function2 then function1 else function2 end,
                   case when function1>function2 then function1 else function2 end,
                   function1
                  ) as rnum
            from tablename)
delete from cte where rnum > 1
```

Comment: That's a good answer, but deleting is not enough. A check constraint must be added to prevent future duplicates as well.

Answer (score 1):

To delete all duplicates you could proceed like this:

Add a new column `temp_pk` and update it with unique values (rownum for example or you can use a sequence as well). Once the column is filled, define the PK over it.

Then you should be able to use this query to delete duplicate data:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE temp_pk IN
(
    SELECT Max(temp_pk) AS pkToDelete
    FROM
        (
            SELECT temp_pk, A, B
            FROM table
            WHERE A<=B
        UNION ALL
            SELECT temp_pk, B, A
            FROM table
            WHERE A>B
        ) AS u
    GROUP BY A, B
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

After that drop the the PK and the temp_ok column and redefine a PK over UserID, so this doesn't happen again the future.

A/B = your Function1/Function2 columns