# How to delete multiple rows having same value in one column?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table Income where I want to delete all, but one, rows that have same value in the column "Date", say 2016-05-08. Can someone help? TIA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicate rows in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: How would you pick that one row? In any case, the duplicate question shows the various ways to identify and delete duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using row number:

```
with todelete as (
      select i.*, row_number() over (partition by date order by date) as seqnum
      from income
     )
delete todelete
    from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

You can control *which* row is kept by adjusting the `order by` clause.

Comment: Be sure to write `[date]` and not `date` as the column name