# Delete duplicate rows from dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset containing duplicate rows

```
DivID  Account_Code  Name
1         CDF400      Caledon
1         CDF400      Caledon
1         CDF400      Caledon
1         BRF205      Brightside
1         BRF205      Brightside
1         FRO400      Fireburn
1         FRO400      Fireburn
```

Could anyone supply me with a query to remove the duplicate lines

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there are a lot of similiar questions here on SO, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()` function to check duplication and remove

```
delete d from (
   select *,
          row_number() over (partition by Account_Code, Name order by DivID) Seq 
   from table
) d
where Seq  > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS(

   SELECT DivID,
          Account_Code,
          Name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DivID,Account_Code,Name ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN
   FROM Table1
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Demo

> http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c17dad6539da425bc1371614f0cbb1b2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TRy this:

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DivID,Account_Code,Name 
                                       ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
         FROM   YourTable)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `Distict`Function In Your Select Query .

```
     SELECT DISTINCT statement
```