# Use a CTE to UPDATE or DELETE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, common-table-expression, sql-delete, mysql-8.0

The new version of MySQL, 8.0, now supports [**Common Table Expressions**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).

According to the manual:

> A WITH clause is permitted at the beginning of SELECT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements:

```
WITH ... SELECT ...
WITH ... UPDATE ...
WITH ... DELETE ...
```

So, I thought, given the following table:

```
ID lastName firstName
----------------------
1  Smith    Pat
2  Smith    Pat
3  Smith    Bob
```

I can use the following query:

```
WITH ToDelete AS 
(
   SELECT ID,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lastName, firstName ORDER BY ID) AS rn
   FROM mytable
)   
DELETE FROM ToDelete;
```

in order to delete duplicates from the table, just like I could do in [**SQL Server**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/feef4/1).

It turns out I was wrong. When I try to execute the `DELETE` stament from MySQL Workbench I get the error:

> Error Code: 1146. Table 'todelete' doesn't exist

I also get an error message when I try to do an `UPDATE` using the CTE.

So, my question is, how could one use a `WITH` clause in the context of an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement in MySQL (as cited in the manual of version 8.0)?

Comment: If you replace your delete statement with `SELECT * FROM ToDelete` does that also throw an error, or does it work?

Comment: @Tim It works as expected

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be a published bug in MySQL `8.x`.  From this [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88397):

> In the 2015 version of the SQL standard, a CTE cannot be defined in UPDATE; MySQL allows it but makes the CTE read-only (we're updating the documentation now to mention this).
>   This said, one could use a view instead of the CTE; then the view may be updatable, but due to the presence of window functions it is materialized into a temporary table (it is not merged) so is not updatable (we're going to mention it in the doc as well).
>
> All the above applies to DELETE too.

If you follow the above bug link, you will see a workaround suggested for using a CTE, but it involved joining the CTE to the original target table in a one-to-one mapping.  Based on your example, which is a blanket delete, it is not clear what workaround you need, were to proceed using a CTE for your delete.

Comment: Good research job!

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos By the way, it's not really a "bug," any more than the other quirks in MySQL we all know about (e.g. check constraints, which you can define, but don't actually work).  It's an incomplete feature, to be finished, possibly, in a later release, we hope :-)

Comment: iám wondering would this "bug" also apply to MariaDB 10.2.1+?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Good question, I don't know.  If it's forked from the same build of MySQL, I would assume yes; in any case, you may check that documentation.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I know what you mean about MariaDB...and I do recall that it's had some features ahead of what MySQL has.  It would be nice if it supported SQL Server style CTE based deletes.

Answer (score 8):

Since the CTE is not updatable, you need to refer to the original table to delete rows.  I think you are looking for something like this:

```
WITH ToDelete AS 
(
   SELECT ID,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lastName, firstName ORDER BY ID) AS rn
   FROM mytable
)   
DELETE FROM mytable USING mytable JOIN ToDelete ON mytable.ID = ToDelete.ID
WHERE ToDelete.rn > 1;
```

Comment: This is a nice work around but it still needs a `JOIN`. The purpose of me using a `CTE` (this is my preferable `DELETE` method in SQL Server for cases like this) is to make the `DELETE` statement as simple as possible.