# Long SQL query fails

Tags: mysql, sql

This query I retrieved from another forum fails. When running it in `Sequel PRO` I get this error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS bar
)
SELECT
    q.id
FROM
    questions q
INNER JOIN
    concat_data cd
ON
 ' at line 27
```

This I the query I'm trying to run:

```
WITH raw_data AS (
    SELECT
        q.id AS id
      , q.description AS description
      , q.source AS source
      , q.image AS image
      , GROUP_CONCAT(c.choice ORDER BY c.choice) AS foo
    FROM
        questions q
    INNER JOIN
        choices c
    ON
        c.question_id = q.id
    GROUP BY
        q.id
      , q.description
      , q.source
      , q.image
),
concat_data AS (
    SELECT
        MIN(id) AS min_id
      , CONCAT(description, source, image, foo) AS bar
    FROM
        raw_data
    GROUP BY
        CONCAT(description, source, image, foo) AS bar
)
SELECT
    q.id
FROM
    questions q
INNER JOIN
    concat_data cd
ON
    cd.min_id = q.id;
```

And for the sake of it. Im trying to find duplicates from `questions` table that has a pivot table `choices`. Remove the duplicates and keep the the "original".

Comment: remove the `AS bar` from `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Adam . . . If you want an answer to your "real" question, ask another question and provide sample data and desired results.  Fixing the syntax on this query may not really be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

While you need "as bar" in the select portion (to make the alias "bar" for that concatenation), you do NOT need the "AS bar" in the GROUP BY clause.

```
GROUP BY
    CONCAT(description, source, image, foo)
```

should do.

Comment: Thanks! That returns a bunch of ID's, how do I delete them ^^ ? Can I do that with the query?

Comment: @Adam You currently can't use a CTE with a `DELETE` query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799157/use-a-cte-to-update-or-delete-in-mysql

Comment: if you mean you want the SQL to return less information, then you need to add "WHERE" clauses to the statement.  How to do that is well beyond the scope of this question, and indeed, would be better served by a refresher course in SQL.  If you mean you want to take the result set of this SQL and remove the results from the tables, then... see Barmar's response.