# How to delete results using recursive common table expression?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, recursion, common-table-expression

I want to delete all children from a tree structure in sql using a common table expression, but I can't seem to get it working. Here is what my table looks like right now, it's simply two foreign keys referring to the same table. This is the `reply` table

```
| parent_id | child_id  |
|-----------|-----------|
| 1         | 60        |
| 2         | 70        |
| 70        | 80        |
```

And the post table looks like this

```
    | id        | text                 |
    |-----------|----------------------|
    | 1         | "blah blah"          |
    | 2         | "the quick brown fox |
    | 70        | "more text"          |
```

The reply table refers to the post table id

To use this, I currently select the children of a root node. So for example, if the root node was 1, then I would retrieve posts 60. And if the root node was 2, then I would retrieve 70 and 80. I would get 80 because it's a child of 70, and 70 is a child of 2.

To do this, I use this query:

```
WITH recursive cte (parent_id, child_id, text) AS 
( 
           SELECT     reply.parent_id, 
                      child_id, 
                      post.text 
           FROM       reply 
           INNER JOIN post 
           ON         reply.child_id = post.id 
           WHERE      parent_id = ? 
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT     p.parent_id, 
                      p.child_id, 
                      post.text 
           FROM       reply p 
           INNER JOIN post 
           ON         p.child_id = post.id 
           INNER JOIN cte 
           ON         p.parent_id = cte.child_id )
SELECT * 
FROM   cte
```

Ultimately, I just want to delete all of the results recursively, and so I tried this but to no avail.

```
WITH recursive cte (parent_id, child_id, text) AS 
( 
           SELECT     reply.parent_id, 
                      child_id, 
                      post.text 
           FROM       reply 
           INNER JOIN post 
           ON         reply.child_id = post.id 
           WHERE      parent_id = ? 
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT     p.parent_id, 
                      p.child_id, 
                      post.text 
           FROM       reply p 
           INNER JOIN post 
           ON         p.child_id = post.id 
           INNER JOIN cte 
           ON         p.parent_id = cte.child_id ) 
DELETE a 
FROM       reply a 
INNER JOIN cte b 
ON         a.parent_id = b.parent_id 
AND        a.child_id = b.child_id
```

How can I use the results inside of the cte to delete the entries in the original reply table? I should be able to use the delete statement with the `with` keyword, but it doesn't seem to work.

EDITL Nevermind. I'm using MariaDB and it doesn't work. When I tried it on MySQL it worked like a charm. Maybe somebody else will encounter this same issue in the future, or maybe it will be fixed by then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a CTE to UPDATE or DELETE in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799157/use-a-cte-to-update-or-delete-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Switching from MariaDB to MySQL fixed my issue. Thank you everyone.