# How to use DELETE and UPDATE with CTEs?

Tags: mysql, sql

In the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) it says that

A WITH clause is permitted in these contexts:

- At the beginning of SELECT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.

```
    WITH ... SELECT ...
    
    WITH ... UPDATE ...
    
    WITH ... DELETE ...
```

So how do I actually do it? I've tried something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test1(
    val_1 VARCHAR(20),
    val_2 INT
);

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('abc', 12), ('efg', 13), ('hij', -15);

WITH cte_1 (letters, numbers) AS
    (SELECT val_1, val_2 FROM test1)
DELETE FROM cte_1 WHERE numbers=-15;
```

This gives me an error: Error Code: 1288. The target table cte_1 of the DELETE is not updatable

The same thing happens when I try this:

```
WITH cte_1 (letters, numbers) AS
    (SELECT * FROM test1)
UPDATE cte_1 SET numbers=14 WHERE numbers=-15;
```

So how do I actually UPDATE and DELETE FROM a CTE in MySQL? I'm using Workbench 8.0 btw. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a CTE to UPDATE or DELETE in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799157/use-a-cte-to-update-or-delete-in-mysql)

Comment: @underscore_d I saw this topic before but have decided to make my own. Mainly because I got a different error and the topic is over 2 years old meaning the 'bug' could have been fixed by now. Google didn't really help me as all and other websites I visited were either about SQL Server or Oracle. I appreciate your intentions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Your examples are so trivial that no CTE is needed -- just run the condition on the table.

In general, though, you can use the CTE to return the rows *along with the primary key*.  The use `JOIN` on the primary key to identify the rows for updating or deleting.  Of course, any columns would suffice, but the primary key is usually best.

Comment: I know a CTE isn't needed here. I just wanted to have a simple working example. Could you please show me an example using your solution? Appreciate it and thanks for helping.