# Update n rows from a table to n rows in another table (no foreign key)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have 2 tables, `table_1` and `table_2`. `table_1` included all data which I need to update to `table_2`.

**table_1**

| column_2 | column_3 |
| --- | --- |
| b1 | b1 |
| b2 | b2 |

**table_2**

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | a1 | a |
| 2 | a | a | a |
| 2 | a | a | a |
| 1 | a2 | a2 | a |
| 2 | a | a | a |

I need to put all data of `table_1` to `table_2` where `column_1` is a specific number, for example, 1. However, I don't have any foreign key to join these two tables. The only relationship is that `table_1` has n rows, `table_2` also has n rows where `column_1` = 1, and I want n rows in `table_1` to be updated to these n rows in `table_2`.
My result would look like this:

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b1 | b1 | a |
| 2 | a | a | a |
| 2 | a | a | a |
| 1 | b2 | b2 | a |
| 2 | a | a | a |

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to join on a `row_number()` of each table. But it sounds like a bad table design to be honest. More info please...

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin. `table_2` is a real table with primary key id, username, user_id. `table_1` was just a csv-file I import into the database so I don't have to manually edit each rows of `table_2`. I will delete `table_1` after update is finished, so the table structure was designed much more loose than normally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to do that with a scripting language instead of using sql.
get everything `from table2 where column_1=1 order by column_2` to an array of objects like

```
[
 {column_1: 1, column_2: b1, column_3: b1, column_4: a},
 {column_1: 1, column_2: b2, column_3: b2, column_4: a}
]
```

then get everything `from table1 order by column_2` in an array of objects

```
[
 {column_1: b1, column_2: b1},
 {column_1: b2, column_2: b2}
]
```

and for every element in table1, update table2 using column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4 in a where qlause

I dont think any other way to do this...it really a pain if the structure is like that

Comment: I would hope to avoid scripting language if possible since I am giving instruction to a new beginner who just learn phpmyadmin. Unfortunately I don't have enough time to manage database by myself, so I have to just tell them to "write this line to SQL query and press Go", something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear by what logic you would like which rows in table1 to update which in table2. I will assume you just want to go in order: row 1 to row 1, 2 to 2 etc.

What we can do is add a `row_number()` to each table, then join on that.

I'm not 100% on MySQL syntax but hopefully you should get the idea. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799157/use-a-cte-to-update-or-delete-in-mysql) for further "update through join" syntaxes:

```sql
WITH t2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM table_2
    WHERE column_1 = 1
),
t1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM table_1
)
UPDATE t2
SET
    t2.column_2 = t1.column_2,
    t2.column_3 = t1.column_3
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

If you cannot do an update on a `WITH` table, then you must self-join `table2`. You haven't indicated the PK of that table, I will just use column `PK`:

```
UPDATE table_2
SET
    table_2.column_2 = t1.column_2,
    table_2.column_3 = t1.column_3
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM table_2
    WHERE column_1 = 1
) AS t2 ON t2.PK = table_2.PK
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM table_1
)AS t1 ON t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the mysql version I am working on didn't support `WITH`-clause. I don't have permission to update mysql version. The logic you said is exactly what I want.

Comment: Ok I've given you another syntax you could use. If that doesn't work, have a google for "MySQL update with join"

Comment: After realizing my mysql version didn't support row_number(), I used a workaround and change the query a little bit. The syntax is correct but the query didn't affect any row. I had made a sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78f12f/3) for more explanation. I do understand your logic, therefore I couldn't understand why it didn't work.