# How can I delete duplicate (mixture of two rows) rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table like this:

```
id   c1   c2
1    5    abc
2    5    abc
3    2    xyz
4    2    xyz
5    68   sdf
```

I want to remove rows where c1 & c2 are same (that is row with id 2 and 4)

Edit: I tried

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE jobs
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (c1, c2);
```

but got this

> 1834 - Cannot delete rows from table which is parent in a foreign key constraint 'xyz' of table 'abc'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: not duplicate, see the edit @SamiKuhmonen sorry

Comment: A good solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server).

Comment: There are several solutions in the duplicate, not just one. Tried the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suppose the table name is foobar , and c1 and c2 is not nullable .

this query will select the duplicate

```
select d.* from ( select c1 ,c2 , count(*) as cnt , min(id) as mid from foobar         group by c1,c1 ) as e 
       join foobar d on d.c1=e.c1 and d.c2=e.c2 and d.id > e.mid ;
```

You must create a temporary table with the list of all id you want to delete .

```
create table bad_id_foobar as select d.id  from ( select c1 ,c2 , count(*) as cnt , min(id) as mid from foobar         group by c1,c1 ) as e 
       join foobar d on d.c1=e.c1 and d.c2=e.c2 and d.id > e.mid ;
```

this query will delete the duplicate

```
 delete from foobar           where id in ( select b.id from  bad_id_foobar b );
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in three steps.

1. Insert unique records into a tmp table (same table structure as 'jobs').

```html
INSERT INTO tmp (`c1`, `c2`) 
    SELECT c1, c2 
    FROM jobs 
    GROUP BY c1, c2
```

2. Remove or Rename the 'job' table

```html
DROP TABLE job
```

```html
ALTER TABLE job
RENAME job_archived
```

3. Rename 'tmp' table to 'job'

```html
ALTER TABLE tmp
RENAME job
```

This how I do a task like this. There may be a better way to do the same... Cheers!