# Remove duplicates without key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to remove all duplicates in one of my tables. None of them are keys or unique. Tried to google some solutions but they don't seem to work.

```
delete T1
from MyTable T1, MyTable T2
where T1.MyTableCustomer = T2.MyTableCustomer
and T1.MyTableCustomerId = T2.MyTableCustomerId
and T1.MyTableSoldToParty = T2.MyTableSoldToParty
```

So I want to remove all rows where there already exists an equal row with the exact same value on all of the columns.

How can I archive this in SQL Server (2017)?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicate rows in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4):

This is tricky because without any IDs or unique keys, it is hard to specify which record to delete.  However, SQL Server does offer a way to pull it off.  I found a solution on [this page](http://www.codaffection.com/sql-server-article/delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server/) and adapted it to your table.  Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MyTableCustomer, MyTableCustomerId, MyTableSoldToParty ORDER BY MyTableCustomer, MyTableCustomerId, MyTableSoldToParty) AS RN
    FROM MyTable
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1
```

It works by assigning an additional column that is basically a counter for all identical records, and then deletes the records that have a value greater than 1.  This will preserve ONE of the duplicate values and remove all of the others.