# How to delete duplicate records from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with records and I want to delete all duplicate records
name, age, date are columns I am getting from a file.

- `CREATE_DATE` is the column that captures when I loaded the file.
- `file_id` is from the id I am generating based on the `file_log_sys` table
- `stage_id` is an identity column

Sample data:

```
stage_id name age       date         file_id  create_date
---------------------------------------------------------
   1     john   25     2019-02-02    100       2019-04-04
   2     sam    50     2019-01-13    100       2019-04-04
   3     john   25     2019-02-02    101       2019-04-05   
   4     peter  33     2019-01-01    101       2019-04-05
```

I would like to delete the record where file_id = 100 and stage_id = 1 and name= john

I tried:

```
delete min(file) id 
from table
```

and it didn't work.

I want my output to be

```
stage_id name   age    date        file_id     create_date
-----------------------------------------------------------
   2     sam    50     2019-01-13    100       2019-04-04
   3     john   25     2019-02-02    101       2019-04-05   
   4     peter  33     2019-01-01    101       2019-04-05
```

Can you please help me with the query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicate rows in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
    select *,row_number() over(partition by name order by create_Date desc) as rn
    from tablename
)

delete from cte where rn<>1
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. This is what i was expecting to see my results

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your question, but if you just want to delete the record where the file_id = 100 and stage_id = 1 and name= john it is as simple as:

```
delete from your_table where file_id = 100 and stage_id = 1 and name = 'john';
```

Comment: Sorry i might confused you, no i don't want to hard code the values . I gave an example that i want to delete the that particular records from the above set i mentioned. I will have many duplicated records in the table so i am trying to see if i use MIN funcation and delete the duplicate records

Comment: In this case you should accept the answer from @fa06. It will do exactly what you're looking for. Although your question is a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

**Using RowNumber()**

```
WITH TablesCTE AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY file_id ORDER BY file_id  ) AS RowNumber
   FROM TableName
)
DELETE FROM TablesCTE WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

**Alternative Way**

```
DELETE FROM TableName WHERE file_id  NOT IN (SELECT MIN(file_id ) _
    FROM TableName  GROUP BY stage_id,name,age,date)
```