# SQL: find distinct values for only few columns

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table that looks like below:

```
ID    Address1       City   State    Zip      YearBuilt 
1    704 Grant Ave    X        Y     11111      2000
2    704 Grant Ave    X        Y     11111      2000
3    704 Grant Ave    X        Y     11111      2000
4    303 2nd St       A        B     22222      1900
5    303 2nd St       A        B     22222      1900
6    44 North ST      C        D     33333      1950
```

Now I want to have only those rows which have distinct **Address1, City, State, and Zip**. ID cannot be used as an identifier because for same address it has a different ID. I'm okay to keep the top ID.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the results from `SELECT DISTINCT Address1, City, State, Zip
FROM Table`

Comment: What [tag:rdmbs] are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete duplicate rows in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Oso I need the year value too.

Comment: @ParasPasrija . . . "I need the year value too" is not the question that you asked here.  You should ask a new question and show the results that you want.  In the meantime, the one answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(ID), Address1, City, State, Zip FROM ... GROUP BY Address1, City, State, Zip
```

Comment: I also need year, but I cannot group by year

Comment: you can add this column with *Aggregate Function* like MAX, MIN or AVG.