# How can I check and remove duplicate rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

Have problem with quite big table, where are some **null** values in 3 columns - **datetime2** (and 2 float columns).

Nice simple request from [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows#18949) returns only 2 rows where datetime2 is null, but nothing else (same as lot of others):

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(RowId) as RowId, allRemainingCols
   FROM MyTable 
   GROUP BY allRemainingCols
) as KeepRows ON
   MyTable.RowId = KeepRows.RowId
WHERE
   KeepRows.RowId IS NULL
```

Seems to work without datetime2 column having nulls ??

---

There is manual workaround, but is there any way to create request or procedure using TSQL only ?

```
SELECT id,remainingColumns
FROM table
order BY remainingColumns
```

Compare all columns in XL (15 in my case, placed =ROW() in first column as a check and formula next to last column + auto filter for **TRUE**s): `=AND(B1=B2;C1=C2;D1=D2;E1=E2;F1=F2;G1=G2;H1=H2;I1=I2;J1=J2;K1=K2;L1=L2;M1=M2;N1=N2;O1=O2;P1=P2)`

Or compare 3 rows like this and select **all** non-unique rows

```
=OR(
AND(B1=B2;C1=C2;D1=D2;E1=E2;F1=F2;G1=G2;H1=H2;I1=I2;J1=J2;K1=K2;L1=L2;M1=M2;N1=N2;O1=O2;P1=P2);
AND(B2=B3;C2=C3;D2=D3;E2=E3;F2=F3;G2=G3;H2=H3;I2=I3;J2=J3;K2=K3;L2=L3;M2=M3;N2=N3;O2=O3;P2=P3)
)
```

Comment: Have a look at this solution instead, which doesn't use a `JOIN`: [How to delete duplicate rows in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18390574/2029983)

Comment: Either I cannot reproduce your issue ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=27db03b751e7b6c7b203208c5e5c7e37)) or I am not understanding your question. Please provide some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Most likely you do not really understand how floating point values work in a binary system and that is the reason you struggle. To compare floats you generally use a range to know if 2 numbers are "equal" or convert to a specific accuracy and then compare. It does not help to post pseudo-code without labelling as such ("GROUP BY allRemainingCols"). If you join on RowID, then why do you need to compare at all? Something seems off here.

Answer (score 0):

Quite much work to find my particular data/answer...

Most of float numbers were slightly different.

Hard to find, but simple **CAST**(column **as binary**) can show these invisible differences...

Like **96,6666666666667** vs 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040582AAAAAAAAAA**D** vs 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040582AAAAAAAAAA**B** etc.

And visible **96.6666666666667** can return something different way again:
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000**F0D0001AB6A489F2D6F0300**