# Delete query from a count query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to clean up a SQL table that has duplicate `claim_id`s.  How do I make this query to delete duplicate CLAIM_ID by CollectLogDate

```sql
SELECT ID, Claim_ID, InsertDate, CollectLogDate, Count(CollectLogDate) AS CollectLogDate
FROM [dbo].[temp]
GROUP BY ID, Claim_ID, InsertDate, CollectLogDate
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete duplicate rows in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18390574/2029983)

Comment: Can you put add some sample data ?

Comment: What happens if you use SELECT DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0):

Below query will find duplicate claim id's between the date range passed and would delete it from the temp table.

```
delete
from [dbo].[temp]
where claim_id in (
    select claim_id
    from [dbo].[temp]
    where CollectLogDate between 'start_dt' and 'end_dt'
    group by claim_id
    having count(1) > 1
)
```

If your requirement is different from this then add some sample input and output data to your question.

Comment: So if there are multiple rows where claim_id = 10 (for example), you propose to delete ALL of those rows and not keep just one? And why are `'start_dt'` and `'end_dt'` part of your solution?

Comment: Yes above solution does delete all the duplicates ? do you want to keep one and delete rest ? If yes then you can try this.
delete T from 
(select Row_Number() Over(Partition By claim_id  order by collectlogdate desc ) As RowNumber, * From [dbo].[temp]) T
Where T.RowNumber > 1