# duplicate query result when join table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I face issue about duplicate data when join table, here my sample data table I have

**-- Table A**

[image]

I want to join with

**-- Table B**

[image]

this my query notation for join both table,

```
select a.trans_id, name 
from tableA a 
inner join tableB b 
   on a.ID_Trans = b.trans_id
```

and this the result, why I get the duplicating data which should show only two lines of data, please help me to solve this case.

[image]

Comment: You are getting all matches between the two tables.  The results are exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: because you have two rows in table A and two rows in table B that matches so you get 4 rows

Comment: as quick and DIRTY fix  select  distinct a.trans_id, b.name from tableA a inner join tableB b on a.trans_id = b.trans_id

Comment: @eshirvana it should be merge, not 4 rows, but only 2 rows,

Comment: Seems like the problem is your data in `tableA`.

Comment: *"it should be merge, not 4 rows, but only 2 rows, "* that isn't how a `JOIN` works. Perhaps what you *really* want is an `EXISTS`?

Comment: @Sergey I try to find out other solution

Comment: then you need to remove duplicate from tableA,because for 2 records in the tableA you have two corresponding records in the tableB.The result of JOIN is 4 records

Comment: @Larnu so, what u suggest, I cannot remove duplicate row in tableA thisa above only sample for my case tableA has any informations ?

Comment: What do the rows in table A represent? What do the rows in table B represent? Why do you need table A in your query? Why not just `select trans_id, name from tableb`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it just sample, actually tableA has many information I need

Comment: So you actually want to select data from both tables? Why then do you want to join one particular A row to one particular B row? What except for the transaction ID makes you decide which A row to join to which B row?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, as you have been told multiple times in the comments, this is working exactly as you have written, and (more importantly) as intended. You have 2 rows in `tableA` and those 2 rows match 2 rows in your table `tableB` according to the `ON` clause. This means that *each* join operation, for the each of the rows in `tableA`, results in 2 rows as well; thus 4 rows (2 * 2 = 4).

Considering that your table, `TableA` only has one column then it seems that you should be cleaning up that data and deleting the duplicates. There are plenty of examples on how to do that already ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18390574/2029983)).

Perhaps the column you show us in `TableA` is one many, and thus instead you have a denormalisation issue, and instead there should be another table with the details of `Id_trans` and a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT/INDEX` on it. Then you would join fron *that* table to `TableB`.

*Finally*, what you might be after is an `EXISTS`, which would look like this:

```sql
SELECT B.trans_id, B.[name]
FROM dbo.TableB B
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM dbo.TableA A
             WHERE A.ID_Trans = B.trans_id); --Odd that it's called ID_Trans in one table, and Trans_ID in another
```

Comment: It's a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments mentioned your query does exactly what you asked it to do but I think you wanted something like:

```
select a.trans_id, a.name, b.name 
from tableA a 
inner join tableB b on a.trans_id = b.trans_id
group by a.trans_id, a.name, b.name
```

Comment: Why use a `GROUP BY` when there's no aggregation? You'd be better off with a `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two rows in both table with same ID join will make them four. You can use distinct to remove duplicates:

```
select distinct a.trans_id, name 
from tableA a 
inner join tableB b 
   on a.id_trans = b.trans_id
```

But I would suggest to use exists:

```
select trans_id, name 
from tableB b
exists (select 1 from tableA a where a.trans_id=b.trans_id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I will admit that the first answer deserved that downvote since I even forgot to mention Distinct.