# How to delete duplicate records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on a POC where I store videos with links and display them on my website. Unfortunately, I wasn't paying attention and my spider which is crawling for videos inserted some videos twice in my database.

I tried using `INNER JOIN` but it was causing a disconnect and deleting my entire database (11k entries on my test database and 45k on my website).

```
DELETE V1 FROM videos AS V1 INNER JOIN videos AS V2 WHERE V1.title = V2.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you match your own record; table `V1` and `V2` have the very same data, so it will always match the title with itself.

You need to exclude the first record ID which exists in the table.

```
DELETE V1 FROM videos AS V1 
    INNER JOIN videos AS V2 
    WHERE V1.title = V2.title and V1.id > V2.id;
```

This should always leave intact the first record.

Comment: There is a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58687372/5444618

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a JOIN statement.
For Example: DELETE t1 FROM contacts t1
INNER JOIN contacts t2
WHERE
t1.id < t2.id AND
t1.email = t2.email;

You can refer to this link below for more information:

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/