# How to delete duplicate values in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this table in SQL where I would like to delete duplicate values if `paidDate` or `AppDate` are not populated.

With the sample below, I would only like to delete the first `John` row, because neither `paidDate` nor `AppDate` are not populated for that row, but I would like to keep Lisa in this table because it is not a duplicate.

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete duplicate rows in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: Posting images of technical information like sample data, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam to have a question downvoted and then closed or ignored. You will be much more likely to get a good, prompt answer if you **edit the question** to replace the image with well-formatted text for the sample data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Row = 1". The "row 1" is your header .

Comment: @Larnu It's confusing, but I think my edit clears it up. And if I got it wrong, the OP is free to correct it. Play silly games (ask a confusing question), win silly prizes.

Comment: No @Larnu that  does not my question by Row = 1. I meant Row =2 where AppDate and PaidDate is NULL
If it works right Row =2 will be deleted and Row = 5 will stay because it does not have duplicates

Comment: What happens if 2 (or more) rows both have `NULL` for both columns?

Comment: Then I would only like to keep 1 of those of 2 rows @Larnu
In real I will be using ClaimNumber instead of FullName to ensure I have unique values

Comment: Sample data and expected results (showing all edge cases) *as text* not images would help immensely

Answer (score 2):

Just an alternative approach, using a CTE and a windowed functions:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT FullName,
            PaidDate,
            AppDate,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN PaidDate IS NOT NULL OR AppDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS C
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE C > 0
  AND PaidDate IS NULL
  AND AppDate IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE m1
FROM MyTable m1
LEFT JOIN MyTable m2 ON m2.FullName = m1.FullName 
    AND (m2.PaidDate IS NOT NULL or m2.AppDate IS NOT NULL)
WHERE m1.PaidDate IS NULL AND m1.AppDate IS NULL
    AND m2.FullName IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
DELETE FROM MyTable m1
WHERE m1.PaidDate IS NULL AND m1.AppDate IS NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT 1 
       FROM MyTable
       WHERE FullName = m1.FullName AND (AppDate IS NOT NULL OR PaidDate IS NOT NULL)
    )
```

The second NOT EXISTS approach tends to run a little faster, but my own history makes me much faster at writing/maintaining the first exclusion join option.

I really hate using `FullName` as a key like this. It's rare for a dateset to ensure values like full name are distinct between entities. It's very common to find legitimate duplicate names.

Comment: Thank you this worked, yes instead of FullName I'm using claimNumber