# How could I remove duplicate rows in SparkSql？

Tags: sql

My data is like this:

| Code | Time | Total Value | Model Type | First Status | Second Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 07/06/2022 06:45:42 | 23456 | MXJ | Turn On | Turn Off |
| 11111 | 07/06/2022 06:45:42 | 23456 | MXJ | Turn On | Turn Off |
| 11111 | 03/02/2022 08:01:11 | 78231 | MXJ | Turn On | Turn Off |
| 22222 | 04/03/2022 13:23:54 | 20134 | MXJ | Turn On | Turn Off |
| 22222 | 04/03/2022 13:23:54 | 20134 | MXJ | Turn On | Turn Off |

The result I Want:

| Code | Time | Total Value | Model Type | First Status | Second Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 07/06/2022 06:45:42 | 23456 | MXJ | Turn On | Turn Off |
| 11111 | 03/02/2022 08:01:11 | 78231 | MXJ | Turn On | Turn Off |
| 22222 | 04/03/2022 13:23:54 | 20134 | MXJ | Turn On | Turn Off |

My code is like this:

```
select * from 
(
  select
     code,
     Time,
     Model Type,
     Total Value,
     First Status,
     lead(First Status, 1, null) over(partition by code order by Time asc) as Second Status
  from file
  where Model Type = 'MXJ'
) t 
where First Status='Turn On' and Second='Turn Off'
limit 5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete duplicate rows in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in your questions is not very clear. However, there are two methods that come to mind in de-duplicating data.

The first is to use `DISTINCT`. So, if you want to remove duplicates based on all of your columns, you can do,

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM <your_table>
```

If you want it to be based on a few columns,

```
SELECT DISTINCT <column_1>, <column_2> ..
FROM <your_table>
```

The other option is to use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`. You can group by the columns that you want to de-duplicate based on and then filter out rows with a count greater than 1,

```
SELECT <column_1>, <column_2> ..
FROM <your_table>
GROUP BY <column_1>, <column_2> ..
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

So, for your situation, I would suggest creating a TEMP VIEW using the query you have already and then applying one of the methods given above,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW tmp
AS
select
  code,
  Time,
  Model Type,
  Total Value,
  First Status,
  lead(First Status, 1, null) over(partition by code order by Time asc) as Second Status
from file
where Model Type = 'MXJ'
    ) t 
where First Status='Turn On' and Second='Turn Off'

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tmp
```