# Reallocate duplicate record references and remove redundant records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have duplicated data in Table 1. All information in the fields listed below must be identical to be considered a duplicate. The table has other columns but these are inconsequential. The unique identifier is PDS_Item_Ref.

| PDS_Item_Ref | ItemRef | Age | Life | Condition | Comments | HS | Picturefile | Immediate | DETAILS_REF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1830 | 32976 | 5 | 26 | Average | No access | 0 | NULL | 0 | 16 |
| 1872 | 32976 | 5 | 26 | Average | No access | 0 | NULL | 0 | 16 |
| 1900 | 32976 | 5 | 26 | Average | No access | 0 | NULL | 0 | 16 |

These records are referenced to other data in Table 2 using the PDS_Item_Ref column. Some or all of the various records may be referenced.

| Collection_Ref | PDS_Item_Ref | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1830 | 3 |
| 1001 | 1872 | 5 |
| 1002 | 1900 | 6 |
| 1003 | 1830 | 6 |

I need to update the PDS_Item_Ref field in Table 2 to select the duplicated item with the lowest [PDS_Item_Ref] and then delete the remainder of the now redundant records in Table 1. In the example above, item 1830 would be retained and all others would be removed.

Comment: Does these answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) [How to delete duplicate rows in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in a lot of ways, I prefer to use a three-step model:

1. Get duplicates into a temporary table
2. Update referenced tables
3. Remove duplicates from main table

```sql
DROP TABLE #maintable
DROP TABLE #dupes
DROP TABLE #updatetable
SELECT  *
INTO #maintable
FROM    (
        VALUES  (1830, 32976, 5, 26, N'Average', N'No access', 0, N'NULL', 0, 16)
        ,   (1872, 32976, 5, 26, N'Average', N'No access', 0, N'NULL', 0, 16)
        ,   (1900, 32976, 5, 26, N'Average', N'No access', 0, N'NULL', 0, 16)
        ,   (1901, 32976, 5, 26, N'Average', N'Has access', 0, N'NULL', 0, 16)
    ) t (PDS_Item_Ref,ItemRef,Age,Life,Condition,Comments,HS,Picturefile,Immediate,DETAILS_REF)
    
SELECT  PDS_item_ref, min_ref
INTO #dupes
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   MIN(PDS_item_ref) OVER(partition BY ItemRef,Age,Life,Condition,Comments,HS,Picturefile,Immediate,DETAILS_REF ORDER BY pds_item_ref) AS min_ref
    FROM    #maintable
) x
WHERE   x.min_ref <> PDS_Item_Ref

-- create index...
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_#dupes ON  #dupes (PDS_item_ref)

SELECT  *
INTO #updatetable
FROM    (

    VALUES  (1000, 1830, 3)
    ,   (1001, 1872, 5)
    ,   (1002, 1900, 6)
    ,   (1003, 1830, 6)
) t (Collection_Ref,PDS_Item_Ref,Quantity)


-- update dups...
SET xact_abort ON;

BEGIN TRAN
    
    UPDATE  t
    SET PDS_Item_Ref = d.min_ref
    FROM    #updatetable t
    INNER JOIN #dupes d
        ON  d.PDS_item_ref = t.PDS_item_ref
    
    -- update others...
    
    -- Finally delete
    
    DELETE  t
    FROM    #maintable t
    INNER JOIN #dupes d
        ON  d.PDS_item_ref = t.PDS_Item_Ref

    SELECT  *
    FROM    #updatetable
    SELECT  *
    FROM    #maintable
COMMIT TRAN;
```

First I create some test data and then get all duplicate rows. `MIN(PDS_item_ref) OVER(partition BY ItemRef,Age,Life,Condition,Comments,HS,Picturefile,Immediate,DETAILS_REF ORDER BY pds_item_ref)` is a window aggregate designed for two things, to find groups by all the columns and get the minimum ID for each group.

`WHERE   x.min_ref <> PDS_Item_Ref` this ensures we only get the duplicate rows of the groups

Finally we can update the related tables and delete from the main one. It's a good idea to do things in transaction so you don't end up with partially updated data in case something goes wrong.

And most importantly, create a backup before starting working on this.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you, really appreciate your time and effort on this