# PostgreSQL equivalent to SQLite ROWID

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

With the new IDENTITY type in Postgresql 10, I wonder if there is anything similar to `ROWID` in SQLite which is a pseudo-column to get the primary key.

I want to do something like:

```
SELECT ROWID FROM Table
```

in Postgresql and get the primary key.

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626481/rowid-equivalent-in-postgres-9-2) because `ROWID` in Oracle does not give you the primary key.

Comment: aw you beat me by 4 seconds lol

Comment: I somehow beat myself also.

Comment: Sorry to all of you, but Oracle's `ROWID` is different than SQLite's `ROWID`.

Comment: So what does SQLite's `rowid` do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It gives the primary key while `ROWID` in Oracle is the address of the row (which is not the primary key).

Comment: A primary key is a constraint on one or more columns, not a function

Comment: That's why the DBMS that supports such a pseudo-variable have a different behavior when the primary key is compound (look at `$IDENTITY` in SQL Server).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you don't know the answer, please don't post such comments.

Comment: Postgres (like many other DBMS) does not automatically create a primary key. You need to declare it based on one or more columns. If you don't do that. `ctid` is the closest thing you get: a value that uniquely identifies a row (but might change over time for one specific row). So if you want a primary key, declare one. If you need the values to be created automatically use a `serial` or `identity` column.