# Cumulative count for a specified value in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in Sql Sever that looks like this,

```
Br     Type    Sales
102     A       20
102     B       10
102     D       8
102     F       12
103     A       18
103     C       7
103     D       15
103     E       3
```

I want to create a new table in SQL Server that adds a column to the existing table above that provides a cumulative count for each unique Br column and sorts the data Ascending according to the sales column.

The new table should look like this,

```
BrCount    Br     Type    Sales
1          102     D       8
2          102     B       10
3          102     F       12
4          102     A       20
1          103     E       3
2          103     C       7
3          103     D       15
4          103     A       18
```

I am not sure where to start. I thought about using some kind of loop that analyse at each iteration what Br number a row contain and update the BrCount column with the previous value + 1 or just a 1 if the Br number from the previous row does not match, but i struggle to find examples on such kind of loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ranking function [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to do so:

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY br
                    ORDER BY Sales) AS BRCount,
  Br, 
  Type,
  Sales
FROM SalesTable;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1103/1)

This will give you:

```
| BRCOUNT |  BR | TYPE | SALES |
|---------|-----|------|-------|
|       1 | 102 |    D |     8 |
|       2 | 102 |    B |    10 |
|       3 | 102 |    F |    12 |
|       4 | 102 |    A |    20 |
|       1 | 103 |    E |     3 |
|       2 | 103 |    C |     7 |
|       3 | 103 |    D |    15 |
|       4 | 103 |    A |    18 |
```

Comment: Very nice. +1 for the SQL Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 1):

According to your example, what you are looking for is a **query** on the existing table using one of the [ranking functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx):

```
SELECT 
  Rank() OVER(PARTITION BY br BY Sales) AS BRCount,
  Br, 
  Type,
  Sales
FROM MyTable
```

You might want to use `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER`. You could read more about the differences in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747327/sql-rank-versus-row-number) excellent SO thread.