# oracle sql query for second maximum list

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table of of employee_sale

```
id  product   quantity
3    y        6
1    x        2
1    y        5
2    x        4
3    x        3
3    y        5
3    X        5
4    y        3
4    y        4
```

i want to select list of employee id, product and second maximum quantity against all products.

please help with necessary sql query

thanks

Comment: And, what have you tried?

Comment: @RagingBull i tried this but this query is not working perfactly.
select id,product, MAX(quantity) from employee_sale where quantity not in(select max(quantity) from employee_sale ) group by id,product

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `rank()` function for this:

```
SELECT id, product, quantity
FROM   (SELECT id, product, quantity, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id, product ORDER BY quantity DESC) 
               AS rk
        FROM   employee_sale)
WHERE  rk = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives:

1. Using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

   ```
   SELECT id,product,quantity FROM
   (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY quantity DESC) as RN
   FROM employee_sale) T
   WHERE RN=2
   ```
2. Using `RANK()`:

   ```
   SELECT id,product,quantity FROM
   (SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY quantity DESC) as Rnk
   FROM employee_sale) T
   WHERE Rnk=2
   ```

Result:

```
ID  PRODUCT  QUANTITY
2   x        4
1   y        5
```

Comment: Both valid options.  @OP, please note that if you decide to use ROW_NUMBER(), it assigns the row number arbitrarily for duplicate values.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7747406/62640