# update column with incremental value

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table like this

```
userid | points | position
1      | 100    | NULL
2      | 89     | NULL
3      | 107    | NULL
```

i need a query for update the position column ordering by points desc, example result:

```
userid | points | position
1      | 100    | 2
2      | 89     | 3
3      | 107    | 1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like taking the name of your post and putting it into Google with SQL in front of it?

Comment: yes, but nothing is useful for the requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use physical columns that depend on values in other rows, otherwise you have to update the entire table every time one row changes.  Use a view or other mechanism to calculate the position on the fly.

The query to calculate "position" would look something like:

```
SELECT 
    userid, 
    points, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS position
```

However, if you *have* to make it an `UPDATE` then you could use something like

```
UPDATE a
SET a.position = b.position
FROM {table_name} a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        userid, 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS position
        FROM {table_name}
) b
ON a.userid = b.userid
```

but keep in mind that you will need to run the update *every time the table is updated*, so performance may be an issue if it's a decent size table that gets updated a lot.

Comment: sorry but i need to update column not to obtain an incrementa id

Comment: Then use the same philosophy with an update query.  By the way, given that this answer does not have anything to do with incremental ids, are you sure you actually understand it?

Comment: @DaniloCalzetta I added a potential `UPDATE` query with the same caveats.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider using DENSE_RANK() instead of RANK() when you want to increment the ranking of your 'position' by 1 as the 'points' change.  RANK() will do what you want, though it will create number sequence gaps according to how many duplicate 'userids' are equal in 'points' standing's (if that's ever the case in your spec).

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747327/sql-rank-versus-row-number) for the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
UPDATE t
SET position = t2.position
FROM table t
JOIN (
    SELECT 
    userid, 
    points, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS position
    FROM table) t2 ON t2.userid = t.userid
```