# Using SQL Server, how can I find the topselling products by each salesperson in AdventureWorks2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

For a homework assignment, I am trying to find the topselling products by each salesperson in January 2012 using AdventureWorks2014.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT      
    Person.Person.LastName, Person.Person.FirstName, 
    Person.Person.MiddleName, 
    Employee_1.JobTitle, 
    Sales.SalesPerson.SalesQuota, Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate, 
    Production.Product.Name, 
    SUM(distinct OrderQty) AS Expr2
FROM
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail 
INNER JOIN
    Production.Product ON Sales.SalesOrderDetail.ProductID = Production.Product.ProductID 
INNER JOIN
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader ON Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID 
                           AND Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID 
                           AND Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID 
INNER JOIN
    Sales.SalesPerson ON Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID = Sales.SalesPerson.BusinessEntityID 
                      AND Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID = Sales.SalesPerson.BusinessEntityID 
                      AND Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID = Sales.SalesPerson.BusinessEntityID 
                      AND Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID = Sales.SalesPerson.BusinessEntityID 
INNER JOIN
    HumanResources.Employee AS Employee_1 
INNER JOIN
    Person.Person ON Employee_1.BusinessEntityID = Person.Person.BusinessEntityID 
        ON Sales.SalesPerson.BusinessEntityID = Employee_1.BusinessEntityID 
        AND Sales.SalesPerson.BusinessEntityID = Employee_1.BusinessEntityID
WHERE       
    (Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31')
GROUP BY 
    Person.Person.LastName, Person.Person.FirstName, Person.Person.MiddleName, 
    Employee_1.JobTitle, 
    Sales.SalesPerson.SalesQuota, Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate, 
    Production.Product.Name
ORDER BY  
    Person.Person.LastName, Production.Product.Name
```

I can not figure out how to add all of the orderqty for each individual product. In the top two rows of results I have the same product sold by the same person. I want to add those together and then find the top 5 products that each salesperson has?

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to use RANK() and PARTITION BY.  There are plenty of examples out there, such as www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/SQLServer/Rank.htm

Comment: @MikeGledhill [sql server `rank()` versus `row_number()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747327/sql-rank-versus-row-number) -- I think you meant `row_number()`

Answer (score 0):

My initial goal would be to reduce the aggregation dataset down to the fewest required number tables to perform the aggregation (`SalesOrderHeader, SalesOrderDetail`) and join that to the table with the additional information (e.g. `Person, Employee`).

I included the `Product` table in the aggregation subquery, but it could be done after the aggregation query and join to the ProductId (after adding it to the `group by` and `select`) instead.

---

There are many ways to do this, here are some:

**cross [apply](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)** version:

```
select
      p.LastName
    , p.FirstName
    , p.MiddleName
    , e.JobTitle
    , s.SalesQuota
    , s.OrderDate
    , s.ProductName
    , s.TotalQty 
  from Person.Person as p on 
    inner join HumanResources.Employee as e on e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
    cross apply ( 
      select top 5 /* 5 rows */ 
        soh.SalesPersonID
      , p.ProductName
      , TotalQty = sum(OrderQty)
      from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as soh 
        inner join Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod on soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
        inner join Production.Product as pr on sod.ProductID = pr.ProductID 
        where soh.OrderDate between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31'
          and s.SalesPersonID = p.BusinessEntityID /* per person */
        group by soh.SalesPersonID, p.ProductName
        order by sum(OrderQty) desc 
        /* ordered by sum(OrderQty) descending */
    ) s
```

**[top with ties](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)** version:

```
select top 5 with ties 
    p.LastName
  , p.FirstName
  , p.MiddleName
  , e.JobTitle
  , s.SalesQuota
  , s.OrderDate
  , s.ProductName
  , s.TotalQty 
    from Person.Person as p on 
      inner join HumanResources.Employee as e on e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
      inner join ( 
        select 
          soh.SalesPersonID
        , p.ProductName
        , TotalQty = sum(OrderQty)
        from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as soh 
          inner join Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod on soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
          inner join Production.Product as pr on sod.ProductID = pr.ProductID 
          where soh.OrderDate between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31'
          group by soh.SalesPersonID, p.ProductName
      ) on s.SalesPersonID = p.BusinessEntityID
order by row_number() over (partition by p.BusinessEntityID order by s.TotalQty desc)
/* returns all rows where row_number() over() evaluates to 1,2,3,4 ,or 5 */
```

**[common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)** with **[row_number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** version:

```
with top5 as (
select
      p.LastName
    , p.FirstName
    , p.MiddleName
    , e.JobTitle
    , s.SalesQuota
    , s.OrderDate
    , s.ProductName
    , s.TotalQty 
    , rn=row_number() over (partition by p.BusinessEntityID order by s.TotalQty desc)
  from Person.Person as p on 
    inner join HumanResources.Employee as e on e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
    inner join ( 
      select 
        soh.SalesPersonID
      , p.ProductName
      , TotalQty = sum(OrderQty)
      from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as soh 
        inner join Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod on soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
        inner join Production.Product as pr on sod.ProductID = pr.ProductID 
        where soh.OrderDate between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31'
        group by soh.SalesPersonID, p.ProductName
    ) on s.SalesPersonID = p.BusinessEntityID
)

select
      LastName
    , FirstName
    , MiddleName
    , JobTitle
    , SalesQuota
    , OrderDate
    , ProductName
    , TotalQty 
  from top5
  where rn < 6
```