# How to get Min(some column value) with primary key ID and max(some column value) with primary key ID with in a single query or nested query in SQL

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2008

I need to get both min and max values of two separate columns with their unique primary key id value.

Anyone ready to help me? Thanks in advance!

```
    select  ID as ID, min(FROMTIME) as FROMTIME,ID as ID,max(TOTIME) as TOTIME,sum(DIFFERENCE_TIME) as DIFFERENCE_TIME   from ( 
  select PersonalBevorzugteArbeitszeiten.PersonalBevorzugteArbeitszeitID ID, zeitvon  FROMTIME ,ZeitBis  TOTIME,DATEDIFF(SECOND,zeitvon,zeitbis) as DIFFERENCE_TIME  from PersonalBevorzugteArbeitszeiten   join personal on personal.PersonalNr  = PersonalBevorzugteArbeitszeiten.PersonalNr   where personal.PersonalNr  = 5  ) as a group by  ID
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Here it's I tried.Can you give a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a window function in a subquery to get the relevant ordinality of the two columns and then select from this.

```
with rns as (
   select pk, col1, col2,
   ROW_NUMBER() over (order by col1 desc) rn_max, 
   ROW_NUMBER() over (order by col2 asc) rn_min
)
select pk, 
case when rn_max = 1 then col1 else col2 end as val,
case when rn_max = 1 then 'MAX' else 'MIN' end as max_min 
from rns 
where rn_max = 1 or rn_min = 1
```

where you can then use RANK() instead or ROW_NUMBER() depending on how you want to handle multiple pks with the same value as per ([SQL RANK() versus ROW_NUMBER()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747327/sql-rank-versus-row-number))

Comment: I could't get your point...Can you explain and give a piece of example?

Comment: The line 
`ROW_NUMBER() over (order by col1 desc) rn_max` is called a window function.

This is a function performed on a window or slice/grouping of your data specified in the `over()` section.

So here you are saying give me the `row_number` when you order the data by `col1 descending`

You then do a similar thing looking at the max of the other category.

You now have a subquery which looks like
`pk, col1, col2, ranking of pk for col1 desc, ranking of pk for col2 asc`
so you can now select the rows from this query where the rankings = 1 i.e. are the max of col1 or the min of col

Comment: The case when is then used to switch between the two states for a concise result but its not needed really to pull the information

Answer (score 0):

Consider one table with 3 columns (PID,Price1,Price2)
here PID is the primary key

**for min value :**
1) select PID,Price1 from TableName where Price1 = (select MIN(Price1) from 
   TableName)
2) select top 1 PID,Price1 from TableName order by Price1

**for max value :**
1) select PID,Price2 from TableName where Price2 = (select MAX(Price2) from TableName)
2) select top 1 PID,Price2 from TableName order by Price2 desc

Comment: I need both Min and Max values of two columns in a single query.You are divides into two distincts. How to make use of it as single one?

Comment: You can do it using the  subquery, try this query => 
 
 select top 1 
 PID AS MaxID,
 Price1 AS Maxvalue,
 (select top 1 PID from TableName order by Price2  ) As MinID,
 (select top 1 Price2 from TableName order by Price2  ) As MinVAlue,
 from TableName order by Price1 desc